# Calculo de .scss para .sass

Tags: css, sass, gulp

Estou criando um grid system dinâmico utilizando sass e o gulp-sass para compilar.

Tenho este código:

```
$col-margin: 15px
.row
  width: 100%
  max-width: 1170px
  margin: 0 auto
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: wrap
// cols
=col($cols)
  width: calc(((100% * $cols) /12) - ($col-margin * 2))
  margin: $col-margin
  box-sizing: border-box
```

Ou seja a margem é 15px. Ao compilar pelo terminal, utilizando o gulp-sass tenho este erro:

```
    [20:22:31] Starting 'sass'...
[20:22:31] Starting 'watch'...
[20:22:31] Finished 'watch' after 31 ms
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    assets\gs.sass
Error: Incompatible units: 'px' and '%'.
        on line 10 of assets/gs.sass
>>   width: ((100% * $cols) /12) - ($col-margin * 2);
   -----------^

[20:22:31] Finished 'sass' after 95 ms
[20:22:31] Starting 'default'...
[20:22:31] Finished 'default' after 20 μs
```

Answer (score 0):

Então, o que acontece é que o Sass assim como todos os pré-processadores não executam calculos com diferentes unidades de media.. e no caso ele está tentando executar e compilar isso..

A solução nesse caso é fazer com que ele não tente resolver essa parte e deixe que o calc() resolva depois de compilado..

para isso vc precisa das um "escape" para o que vc nao quer que o saas se meta..

Faz assim:

```
#{calc(((100% * $cols) /12) - ($col-margin * 2))}
```

Usando essa notação de #{} envolvendo a parte que vc não quer que o Sass se meta deve resolver seu problema :)

Mais infos: http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_

Comment: Não resolveu ele aparece a formula direto no .css:
`.col-10 {
    width: calc(((100% * $cols) / 12) - ($margin-col * 2));
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: red;
}`

Comment: width: #{calc((#{(100% * $cols)} / 12) - #{($margin-col * 2)})}... não lembrava desta possibilidade ajudou bastante. Está resolvido.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido, o correto é:

```
width: #{calc((#{(100% * $cols)} / 12) - #{($margin-col * 2)})}
```